# How to connect simplesamlphp to an Oracle database?

Tags: php, oracle, simplesamlphp

I have a simplesamlphp installed and successfully connected to a MySQL database, but now I need to connect to an Oracle database.

I used the following configuration in authsource.php

```
'example-sql' => array(
    'sqlauth:SQL',
    'dsn' => 'oci:dbname=//serverHost/databasename',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'query' => "SELECT UserIdentity, AccountType,
    FROM Users 
    WHERE UserIdentity = :userid 
    AND UserPassword =MD5(:password) ",
),
```

but I could not login. I received no errors.

Comment: Don't know anything about this framework, but you'll want to make sure `display_errors = on` is in your php.ini file, as you won't see any errors otherwise. Might want to include a bit more code as well, rather than just one element in an array.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "database name"? Oracle doesn't make things that simple. It uses either of what it calls an SID or service name. Which is it?